# Redux action doesn't dispatch after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I have an issue with redux and probably useEffect(I am not sure where my mistake is). I am trying to get information from [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co) and store information in the redux state. The problem is that the information about pokemons don't include pokemon types(fire, water, etc.), to solve this I am sending requests to fetch those types from a different endpoint and I want to include these types of specific pokemon to redux state.

**[1-redux state without types of pokemons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NxDV.png)**

**[2-redux state with types of pokemons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L23dK.png)**

My goal is to have a state like in the second picture with types. But when I refresh the page, I only acquire the first picture(actions aren't dispatching). When I change something in my code and save it, I get types as well. I suspect that my problem is in the useEffect, but I couldn't find a solution without creating some nasty loops.

**Note: Page parameter in fetchData coming from PokeAPI, it basically returns 15 pokemon for every page.(For now I am just experimenting on the first page)**

This is my first question in stackoverflow, I already searched for similar questions but those were dealing with different aspects, so I decided to ask myself.

**PokemonList.js --> this is where I need those types**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import _ from "lodash";
import { GetPokemonList, GetSpecificPokemon } from '../redux/actions/PokemonAction';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const PokemonList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pokemonList = useSelector(state => state.PokemonList);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = (page = 1) => {
      dispatch(GetPokemonList(page));
    }

    fetchData();

  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTypes = () => {
      pokemonList.data.forEach(pokemon => {
        dispatch(GetSpecificPokemon(pokemon.name));
      });
    }

    fetchTypes();
    
  }, [dispatch]);


  const showData = () => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(pokemonList.data)) {
      return (
        <div className="pokemon-list-wrapper">
          {pokemonList.data.map((pokemon, index) => {
            return (
              <div className="pokemon-list-element" key={index}>
                <ListGroup>
                  <ListGroupItem action href={`/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`} variant="success">{pokemon.name}
                    <Button style={{ float: "right" }}>Test</Button>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                </ListGroup>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }

    if (pokemonList.loading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    if (pokemonList.errorMessage !== "") {
      return <p>{pokemonList.errorMessage}</p>
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {showData()}
    </div>
  )
};

export default PokemonList;
```

**PokemonAction.js**

```
import axios from "axios"

export const GetPokemonList = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "POKEMON_LIST_LOADING"
    });

    const perPage = 15;
    const offset = (page * perPage) - perPage;

    const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${perPage}&offset=${offset}`);

    dispatch({
      type: "POKEMON_LIST_SUCCESS",
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: "POKEMON_LIST_FAIL"
    });
  }
}

export const GetSpecificPokemon = (name) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`);

    dispatch({
      type: "SPECIFIC_POKEMON_SUCCESS",
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: "SPECIFIC_POKEMON_FAIL"
    });
  }
}
```

**PokemonListReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: "",
  count: 0
};

const PokemonListReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "POKEMON_LIST_LOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        errorMessage: ""
      };
    case "POKEMON_LIST_FAIL":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: "unable to get pokemon"
      };

    case "POKEMON_LIST_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.payload.results,
        errorMessage: "",
        count: action.payload.count
      };

    case "SPECIFIC_POKEMON_SUCCESS":
      const typesMap = action.payload.types.map((type) => {
        return type.type.name;
      })
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map((pokemon) => pokemon.name === action.payload.name 
                                  ? {...pokemon, types: typesMap}
                                  : pokemon
      ),
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: ""
      }
    case "SPECIFIC_POKEMON_FAIL":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: "unable to get pokemon"
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default PokemonListReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your second useEffect does not wait for your first useEffect to finish and because of that the pokemon list is empty. On code change, since the state already has the pokemon list pre-filled, the second useEffect finds the list and does it's thing. You have to guarantee that the second action is caller right after the first one in order for this to work properly. One way to do this is to dispatch the `GetSpecificPokemon` action for each pokemon before finishing the `GetPokemonList` action. Something like this should work:

```js
export const GetPokemonList = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "POKEMON_LIST_LOADING"
    });

    const perPage = 15;
    const offset = (page * perPage) - perPage;

    const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${perPage}&offset=${offset}`);

    dispatch({
      type: "POKEMON_LIST_SUCCESS",
      payload: res.data
    });
    res.data.result.forEach(pokemon => {
      dispatch(GetSpecificPokemon(pokemon.name));
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: "POKEMON_LIST_FAIL"
    });
  }
}
```

Note that you won't be needing the second `useEffect` if you are doing this. You might also have to change displaying/not displaying the loader part yourself.

Another way is to add `pokemonList` as the second object in the useEffect's array parameter. I haven't tested it yet but this should work. For example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchTypes = () => {
    pokemonList.data.forEach(pokemon => {
      dispatch(GetSpecificPokemon(pokemon.name));
    });
  }

  fetchTypes();

}, [dispatch, pokemonList]);
```

This will call the `useEffect` whenever there is a change in `pokemonList`. In your implementation, `useEffect` is only called once since the value of `dispatch` never really changes after that. Adding `pokemonList` to the array results in the `useEffect` being called when there is a change in `pokemonList` also. Use this approach if you want the `GetPokemonList` action to always be separate from `GetSpecificPokemon` action i.e there are cases when both are not called together. If both are always called together then the first approach is cleaner.

That being said, these implementations actually result in a lot of network calls. The best way is to avoid the second call if possible (change your UI accordingly?) since you do not have any control over the API. If you do have control over the API you could include the extra data in the first request's response.

Edit: Here is the batch logic

```js
const p = pokemonList.map(({ name }) =>
  axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`)
);
const res = await Promise.all(p);
const data = res.map((r) => ({
  ...r.data,
  types: r.data.types.map((type) => type.type.name) // the logic you were using for types
}));

dispatch({
  type: "SPECIFIC_POKEMON_SUCCESS",
  payload: data
});
```

And then update the state in the reducer like

```js
case "SPECIFIC_POKEMON_SUCCESS":
  return {
    ...state,
    data: action.payload,
    loading: false,
    errorMessage: ""
  };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. The first approach that you have suggested works like a charm but the second one (I have tried that before) is causing some loops and constantly dispatching the action. Is it because of the action modifying pokemonList and that useEffect triggered again and again since pokemonList modified every time?

Comment: That may be because you are updating the state 15 different times (for 15 different pokemons). Try batching the requests by making the `GetSpecificPokemon` action accept an array and use `Promise.all` for the network calls. Once you get all the pokemon's details together, you can just update the state once. Again, this is not something I have tried. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I've tried but no luck. I am kind of new to this js world :)) Could you please help me with this? Should I create `let responses= []` and push each response to that array? And then 
`Promise.all(responses).map((response => {
do something in there?})` 

Also after that, payload will be an array of res.data? It is kinda confusing for me, btw thanks for your massive help. @Akhil

Comment: I tried your code in sandbox and what I could find is that you are modifying the same data in both of these requests. This is causing an infinite loop where `GetPokemonList ` edits the pokemon list and then `GetSpecificPokemon` gets called which again edits the pokemon list (even if you batch it) which then calls `GetPokemonList` and the cycle repeats. Are you keen on splitting these to actions? If not the first approach is the best one. Also, I have added the batch login in the original answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried to modify the same data to have a compact and clean state (I hope nothing is wrong with this). 

I have already applied the first approach and will continue with that one. I just wanted to learn about batching requests for different problems in the future :). Many thanks for providing batch logic and your time!